# combinations of python matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

How would I get this output (which is a combination of elements) from a matrix *using no libraries, only pure python?*

Input:

`myList = [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]`

Output:

`myList = [[a, c, e], [a, c, f], [a, d, e], [a, d, f], [b, c, e], [b, c, f], [b, d, e], [b, d, f]]`

EDIT: solution should work for a list of any size with sublists of size 2, the above is just an example

Comment: You need to quote the strings in your test example: `myList = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]

tmp = []
for i in myList[0]:
    for j in myList[1]:
        for k in myList[2]:
            tmp.append([i, j, k])
myList = tmp
print(f"{myList=}")
```

Prints:

```
myList=[['a', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'f'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'f'], ['b', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Comment: how would you make this work for a list of any size, still with sublists of length 2?

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
myList = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
combs = [[x, y, z] for x in myList[0] for y in myList[1] for z in myList[2]]
print(combs)
# [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'f'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'f'], ['b', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f']]
```

Comment: how would you make this work for a list of any size, still with sublists of length 2?